# Getting multiple character inputs inside for loop

Tags: c

```
char c;
int i;
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
 printf("Enter a character : ");`
 scanf("%c",&c);
}
getch();
```

The above code doesn't work properly.It is getting input for only 3 times. I am not able to find solution for it.Please help with it.Thanks in advance !!

Comment: The code does not consume the newline character. If the user enters `a` and hits return the code will read `a` and then read `\n`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because of the new-line character `\n` left behind by the previous `scanf` is read by the `scanf` in the next iteration. Place a space before the `%c` specifier to consume the `\n`

```
scanf(" %c",&c);  
       ^Notice the space
```

Answer (score 0):

`char c` is a single character variable.

In your code, your are reading time and time again characters and storing it into `c`, effectively overwriting it each time. If you would like to input multiple characters, consider using a `character array` likewise:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main (void)
{
    char c[5];
    int  counter;

    for (counter = 0; counter < 5; counter++)
      {
        printf ("Enter a character: ");
        scanf  ("%c\n", &c[i]);
      }

     printf ("The string you input is %s\n", c);

     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you enter `a`, `b` and `c` on the screen then it is actually taking 5 inputs
**Input 1:** `a`
**Input 2:** `\n`
**Input 3:** `b`
**Input 4:** `\n`
**Input 5:** `\n`

The newline is also taken as input